# try catch block or boolean flag?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm not sure about my code, I want to save first into Blob Azure and if it was successful then save that url into my database, I have two ways to do this. The first one using a `boolean variable` named `flag`, if `flag` value is set to true then I can save it into my database, but I'm not sure if this code is the best approach. Is it possible that for some reason the file is not uploaded to `Blob` and even if that happens `flag` value is set to `true`?:
First approach using `boolean flag variable` :

```
using (Stream fileStream = file.InputStream)
{
    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
    flag = true;
}

if (flag == true)
{
    Urls.Add(blockBlob.SnapshotQualifiedUri.ToString());
    db.Save();
}
```

Or should be a better approach to use a `try catch` block?

```
try
{
    using (Stream fileStream = file.InputStream)
    {
        blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
    }
}
catch(Exception)
{
//do something
}

Urls.Add(blockBlob.SnapshotQualifiedUri.ToString());
db.Save();
```

Please explain in your answer the differences between each approach, personally I think that a `try catch` should be a better approach but I want to confirm in here :)

Comment: `flag` will always be set to true, unless it throws an exception (which you're assuming it will do if it fails). So it appears to me the flag won't do anything, as the following code won't execute anyway. Why not put the `Add` and `Save` immediately after `UploadFromStream`, and wrap it all in a try/catch ?

Comment: If `UploadFromStream()` threw an exception, the value of `flag` will never be set to `true` (the method exits before it can be set)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally incases like this, I go a combination of the two and create a method that handles the upload and returns true or false depending on whether the upload was successful, or an exception occurred.

The try catch allows for any potential exceptions to handled appropriately, and the flag becomes simply an indicator to inform you whether the process succeeded or not.

For example, for your upload code, I would create an extension method like this:

```
public static bool TryUploadFile(this CloudBlockBlob blockBlob, File file)
    try
    {
       using (Stream fileStream = file.InputStream)
       {
           blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
       }

       return true;
    }
    catch(Exception)
    {
      //do some logging or other error handling
    }

    return false;
}
```

And then call the method like so:

```
bool succeeded = blockBlob.TryUploadFile(file);

if (succeeded)
{
    Urls.Add(blockBlob.SnapshotQualifiedUri.ToString());
    db.Save();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally the decision about whether to use exceptions or a return value that indicates whether the function succeeds depends on the chances of failure of the function.

Exception handling is fairly expensive, but if it is only used in exceptional cases then this should not lead to performance problems.

The advantage of exception handling is that it makes your code look much cleaner, better to understand and easier to maintain and change.

The lack of a return value that indicated whether the action succeeded or not, usually gives an indication that it is quite exceptional that the action does not succeed. This in contrary to, for instance, opening a file, which quite often might fail and thus uses a return value to report failure.

All three functions you use, `UploadFromStream`, `Add`, and `Save` do not use a return value indicating success (or at least you don't think you need these return values), so it is assumed that these functions seldom fail.

In such cases I'd use the exception method. The code could would look much cleaner:

```
public void Upload(...)
{
    try
    {
        using (Stream fileStream = file.InputStream)
       {
           blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
       }
       Urls.Add(blockBlob.SnapshotQualifiedUri.ToString());
       db.Save();
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
       ProcessProblem(exc);
       throw new MyUploadException(..., exc);
       // or just throw exc
    }
}
```

Now your code looks fairly straightforward. You don't have to remember your progress using temporary variables, and if anything goes wrong, your logging will happen. Note that this will even be the case if the exception is thrown on unexpected places, like when the Dispose at the end of your using statement goes wrong!

This function is also better maintainable. If you add an extra function where it is also fairly exceptional that it fails, just add it, and your catch block will handle the problems.

So the basic rule: if failure is exceptional, use exceptions. Otherwise use return values.